# Information about movement. QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have "my widget" inside a window. Is there any way of knowing if the window was moved from inside  "my widget"? I saw some functions from QWidget but they all only consider moving in relationship between Widget and its parent. Is there any event that is called when the widget move in relation to the screen?

Comment: As mentioned below, i can`t modify window source code.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [moveEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#moveEvent) of the window and get it to send a signal to your widget, which you can then handle in a receiving slot.

In the event of not being able to modify the parent, you can create an object derived from QObject, overload its moveEvent function as though it were the parent window and then install this object as an event filter for the parent window with a call to parent->[installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

The event filter object would be something like this:-

```
class MoveEventMonitor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
     ...
    public:
    signals:
        void ParentMoved();

     protected:
         bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
 };

 bool MoveEventMonitor::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
 {
     if (event->type() == QEvent::Move) 
     {
         emit ParentMoved();
     } 

     // standard event processing
     return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
 }
```

Comment: Can`t do that unfortunately, can`t modify the window source.

Comment: Actually the situation is not as simple as i described, the widget is in some number of widget, it`s parent isn`t the window. So in your solution i would have to set that event handler knowing the structure of the window and i can`t assume that. 

edit: Maybe i can go from parent to parent until there is none and it`s the window. I`m trying it out right now.

Comment: Yes you probably could look for the topmost parent. If not, perhaps it would be better if you described the problem fully in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by leveraging event filtering. Here it's shown for an unmodified `QLabel` widget.

The move event is sent only after you stop moving the window. It's not sent while the window is being moved. Also note that the first event you will receive may have bogus `(0,0)` coordinates. This may be a Qt bug/feature on some platforms.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class WindowMoveMonitor : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   bool eventFilter(QObject * target, QEvent * event) override {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::Move) {
         auto ev = static_cast<QMoveEvent*>(event);
         emit moved(ev->pos());
      }
      return QObject::eventFilter(target, event);
   }
public:
   WindowMoveMonitor(QWidget * widget, QObject * parent = 0) : QObject{parent}
   {
      Q_ASSERT(widget->window());
      widget->window()->installEventFilter(this);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void moved(const QPoint &);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel label{"..."};
   WindowMoveMonitor monitor{&label};
   QObject::connect(&monitor, &WindowMoveMonitor::moved, [&](const QPoint & p){
      label.setText(QStringLiteral("x:%1 y:%2").arg(p.x()).arg(p.y()));
   });
   label.setMinimumSize(200, 50);
   label.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```